# Determining serialization size for C++ objects at runtime using template metaprogramming

Tags: c++, serialization, sizeof, template-meta-programming

I want to use template metaprogramming in order to get the size of the elements that have to be serialized as quick as possible. This means that the result could partlybe inferred at compile time (e.g. the types non variying in size, as the integers) and some other times I must perform some run-time evaluations (e.g. the arrays or the strings).  I've tried to use the following syntax, but it is not correct:

```
// The size of a serialized string is its length plus 1 (the '\0' char)
template<std::string flag = "">
struct ser_size {
    enum {value = flag.length()+1};
};

// Defining an accumulator for a for_each statement
template <typename T>
struct myclass {           // function object type:
public:
    long init = 0;
    long operator() (T i) { init += ser_size<T>(i); return init; }
} myobject;

// A size of an array is its size (the first element points out
// the array size, the remaining elements are the offsets to the 
// array elements, and the remaining elements are the size of the 
// elements in array that have to be serialized
template <typename T, std::vector<T> array>
struct ser_size {
    enum {value = array.size()+std::for_each(array.begin(),array.end()-1,myobject).init};
};

// An integer has always the default size
template<int i = 0>
struct ser_size {
    enum {value = sizeof(int)};
};
```

Another solution I had in mind is the following one:

```
template<typename T> class sizeofClass {
public:
    sizeofClass(T elem) {};
    ~sizeofClass() {};
    virtual long size() = 0;
    virtual T value() = 0;
};

class sizeofInt : public sizeofClass<int> {
    int self;
public:
    sizeofInt(int elem) : sizeofClass(elem) {
        self = elem;
    }
    long size() {
        return sizeof(int);
    }
    int value() {
        return self;
    }
};

class sizeofString : public sizeofClass<std::string> {
public:
    sizeofString(const std::string &elem) : sizeofClass(elem) {
        this->elem = elem;
    }
    long size() {
        return elem.length()+1;
    }
    std::string value() {
        return elem;
    }

private:
    std::string elem;
public:
};
```

At this point I could define an `operator()` "for the size" that, depending on the specific type, creates a object which is a subclass of `sizeofClass` and returns the value of the `size()` method. I could do a similar thing with the `std::vector` if I use myobject which `operator()` calls over each object the `operator()` "for the size":

```
template <typename  T>
class sizeofVector : public sizeofClass<std::vector<T>> {
    std::vector<T> self;
public:
    sizeofVector(std::vector<T> elem) : sizeofClass(elem) {
        self = elem;
    }
    long size() {
        long sizet = std::for_each(self.begin(),self.end(),myobject);
        return self.size();
    }
    std::vector<T> value() {
        return self;
    }

};
```

but, the problem with this approach is that I must allocate objects at run time, while I want to have to perform such computations as efficiently as possible.

Comment: "at runtime using template metaprogramming" I think there is something quite not right there...

Comment: I know, I'm just checking how far I can go with template metaprogramming. I explain better in the subsequent statement: “This means that the result could partlybe inferred at compile time (e.g. the types non variying in size, as the integers) and some other times I must perform some run-time evaluations (e.g. the arrays or the strings).”

Comment: What are you using to do the actual serialization? And could you just add a method to that to calculate the size?

Comment: I think that I already provided some examples on how I would like to return the data size. Plus, strings and bytes are stored with their in-memory representation with an 1-1 mapping.